# Persistent UAC elevation

Tags: c#, uac

Is there any way that I can make a programs UAC elevation permanent across new instances.  I have a program that runs in UAC elevated mode that needs to launch a process in UAC elevated mode but the user will not be at the computer to authorize each time.  Maybe during installation ... but not each time.

Comment: This is not a real problem, have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

A process spawned from an elevated process will already be elevated. There is nothing you need to do to make that work.

Try it:

1. Start `cmd.exe` elevated.
2. Run `notepad.exe` from the command prompt. Notepad will be elevated because it started from an elevated command prompt.
3. Use Notepad to edit a file, such as the HOSTS file (something I frequently do); which would require elevated permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You could just disable UAC completely.

Something more .. desirable is just adding the following line to your application's manifest file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

As vcsjones already pointed out, an elevated process wil spawn elevated proceses, and by requiring your program to run of one, you can be certain things will go alright without the user having to be there all the time.

Answer (score -1):

No.  If you *could*, then everyone *would*, and then the entire purpose of UAC would be defeated.